# Vue-js v-for only posts first record on axios POST

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm stuck and could use a nudge in the right direction!

**Overview:**

I pass a Laravel collection to my Vue.js component ( `:collections_prop="{{ $collection }}"` ). I'm using a `<tr v-for` to iterate over the collection in the component. Inside each `<tr>` is a form with a `<select>` element.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**:

When I change an individual `<select>`, the form should submit and include that particular items `order_id` to the backend.

**What's going wrong**:

My table is displayed as expected, and I can see the individual `order_id's` associated with each `<tr>`. The form submits, but ****only for the first item****.

### Example:

The first `collection` has an `order_id` of 10 and a `qty` of 5. If I select a new qty, the form submits with that `order_id` and the updated `qty`. Perfect!

However, if I change any other `<select>` tag, the `order_id` and `qty` of the first row is the only information submitted.

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <th scope="col">Product</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                        <th scope="col">$</th>
                        <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></th>
                    </thead>

                    <div v-if="collections.length">
                        <tr v-for="collection in collections" :key="collection.order_id">
                            <td>{{ collection.description }}</td>
                            <td>

                                <form @submit="updateQty">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="type" :value="'qty'" id="type" />

                                    <select class="form-control" id="qty" @change="updateQty" >
                                        <option :value="collection.qty" >{{ collection.qty }}</option>
                                        <option v-for="(x, index) in 200" :value="x-1" :key="index" >{{ index }}</option> 
                                    </select>
                                </form>

                            </td>
                            <td>{{ collection.value }}</td>
                            <td>{{ collection.order_id }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: ['collections_prop'],

    data() {
        return {
            collections: this.collections_prop,
            qty: '',
            type: '',
            value: '',
            order_id: '',
        };
    },
  

    mounted() {
        console.log('DisplayTable.vue mounted successfully');
        var type = document.querySelector('#type').value;
    },

    methods: {

        updateQty(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let url = '/update';

            /** Uncomment to see variables being posted */
            console.log('Order id: ' + order_id.value + ', QTY: ' + qty.value);

            axios.post(url, {
                qty: qty.value,
                type: type.value,
                order_id: order_id.value,
            })

            .then(response => {
                this.collections = response.data;
                console.log('Form submitted');
            })
        },

    }
}
</script>
```

### What I've tried:

Too many things to post, but highlights are that I've tried switching this

`<tr v-for="collection in collections" :key="collections.order_id">`

for this

`<tr v-for="(collection, index) in collections" :key="index">` , but no luck.

I've tried to add a `v-model` to the `<select>` tag as well, and I think this is where I'm going wrong but I can't solve it.

I've tried:

`<select id="qty" @change="updateQty" v-model="collection.order_id">`, which causes the `{{ collection.qty }}` to not be displayed inside the `<option>` tag.

I've read about [handling forms](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Dynamic_Select_Options) and [form input bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html), which I'm SURE contains the answer, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Any assistance or even a link to an example would really help me out. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Want to the change the collection when select changes?

Comment: Hey @AliBahraminezhad ! Thank you for reaching out! I want to update the `qty` associated with the individual `order_id` of each product when I change that `<select>` element

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane I believe you'll need to put the `<form>` outside of the `v-for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues you'll want to take care of here. First of all, it doesn't seem like the form is really necessary, so I left it out of my example. If you do need it for whatever reason, it won't hurt to add back in.

Your change event on your select isn't passing back any data to the updateQty method, so it doesn't know how to get any of the data you're supposed to send to the API. If you change your select to look like this, the correct order for that row will get passed back to the method:

```
 <select @change="() => change(event, item)" v-model="item.qty">
    <option v-for="(x, index) in 200" :value="x" :key="index" >{{x}}</option>
 </select>
```

Also, notice that I removed the first option in your select. That would have caused you to have duplicates  - if qty was set to 4 for one of your orders, 4 would show up first in the dropdown and after e (would look like 4,1,2,3,4,etc). By setting v-model to collection.qty (not collection.order_id), the select will always contain the value of collection.qty for that row - if qty is 5, the select will automatically choose 5.

Now, we can set up for change handler to look like this:

```
updateQty(event, order) {
  alert(`New quantity: ${order.qty}`)

  var postObject = {
    qty: order.qty,
    type: 'Wherever this comes from',
    order_id: order.order_id,
  }

  let url = '/update';
  console.log(event)

  /** Uncomment to see variables being posted */
  console.log('Order id: ' + postObject.order_id + ', QTY: ' + postObject.qty);

        // Do your post
  axios.post(url, postObject)
}
```

The order parameter will always be the collection item from the row that was changed. Now, every time any of the selects change, your updateQty method can tell exactly which order it was for. collection.qty is also automatically updated, since v-model is 2-way bound.

Here's a JSFiddle showing all of this code working: http://jsfiddle.net/q4cLoz02/3/

Comment: You have no idea how stoked I am right now. Thank you so much for this - I've honestly been stuck for close to 2 days. I modded this answer slightly to make it work, but this was definitely the trick. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem! Glad you were able to get it working. Vue can take some time to learn, but it's a great framework for client-side development. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="qty" @change="updateQty" >
 <option :value="collection.qty" >{{ collection.qty }}</option>
 <option v-for="(x, index) in 200" :value="x-1" :key="index" >{{ index }}</option> 
</select>
```

You iterate this HTML to all of the items in the collection, right? Ok, the user changes the selected value of the `select` element and it triggers the `@chagne` event. Now the question is `HOW IT SHOULD UNDERSTAND WHAT COLLECTION QTY SHOULD CHANGE?`.

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="qty" @change="() => updateQty(event, collection.id)" >
 <option :value="collection.qty" >{{ collection.qty }}</option>
 <option v-for="(x, index) in 200" :value="x-1" :key="index" >{{ index }}</option> 
</select>
```

And the `updateQty` method:

```
updateQty(e, order_id) {
 var newQty = e.target.value;
 alert(`${order_id} quantity has changed to ${newQty}`)
 // call rest ...
 // 
}
```

I created a JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuL5cr/).

Comment: A much better way to deal with this would be to pass the entire collection object back to the change event, and set v-model="collection.qty" so that you get the benefits of binding. Your Fiddle example doesn't keep track of the values correctly - they always revert back to two, since on re-render the 'id' property isn't actually updated. Using v-model would solve that.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping to point me down the right path here! This helped me think about the problem in a different light. Ultimately @Joseph 's answer solved it but this helped me understand it as well.